# Flutter - Google Play Pre-launch Error - Any ideas what is this about?

Tags: android, flutter, crash, google-play

I am developing an application with Flutter and deploying it to the Google play store. When I upload the app bundle to the tests it failed and I have no idea what these are. It works on iPhone and my emulators without any problem.
I am using the Flutter Beta version because one of the issues I am facing is not fixed in stable versions. So I can't lower the Flutter version.

Dart version 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-165.1.beta)
Flutter version 3.1.0-9.0.pre

```
//app/build.gradle
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

I have these errors in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJGI.png). And I have no idea what these are and how to solve them. Can anyone give some advice?
The details are below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin, PID: 24263
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception thrown in onCreate() of ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.ToggleUserRestriction}: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7033)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6989)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2055)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setUserRestriction(IDevicePolicyManager.java:12057)
    at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(DevicePolicyManager.java:9463)
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.ToggleUserRestriction.start(ToggleUserRestriction.java:49)
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.ToggleUserRestriction.onCreate(ToggleUserRestriction.java:22)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7028)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminWithPolicyForUidLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3259)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminOrCheckPermissionForCallerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3155)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminForCallerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3136)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.setUserRestriction(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:11176)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub.onTransact$setUserRestriction$(IDevicePolicyManager.java:18210)
```

[Device detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnrjP.png)

2nd error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin, PID: 24387
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception thrown in onCreate() of ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.SetUpdatePolicy}: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7033)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6989)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2055)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setSystemUpdatePolicy(IDevicePolicyManager.java:13914)
    at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.setSystemUpdatePolicy(DevicePolicyManager.java:10286)
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.SetUpdatePolicy.start(SetUpdatePolicy.java:51)
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.SetUpdatePolicy.onCreate(SetUpdatePolicy.java:34)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7028)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminWithPolicyForUidLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3259)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminOrCheckPermissionForCallerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3155)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminForCallerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3136)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.setSystemUpdatePolicy(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:12678)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub.onTransact(IDevicePolicyManager.java:5997)
```

[2nd error device info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlsD1.png)

3rd error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.HideApps
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin, PID: 24912
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.isApplicationHidden(IDevicePolicyManager.java:12520)
    at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.isApplicationHidden(DevicePolicyManager.java:9590)
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.HideApps.onStart(HideApps.java:63)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2209)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminWithPolicyForUidLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3259)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminOrCheckPermissionForCallerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3155)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.getActiveAdminForCallerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3136)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.enforceCanManageScopeOrCheckPermission(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:7218)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.enforceCanManageScope(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:7204)
```

[3rd error device info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjTFj.png)

4th error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.HideApps
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin, PID: 28724
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.isApplicationHidden(IDevicePolicyManager.java:12520)
    at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.isApplicationHidden(DevicePolicyManager.java:9590)
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.HideApps.onStart(HideApps.java:63)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2209)
```

[4th error device info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Yzb.png)

Dependencies:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.19.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.4.1
  firebase_database: ^9.0.18
  cloud_firestore: ^3.2.1
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.1
  cloud_functions: ^3.3.2
  firebase_app_check: ^0.0.6+12
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.3
  http: ^0.13.4
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  filter_list: ^1.0.2
  syncfusion_flutter_core: ^20.1.56
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^20.1.56
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  blur: ^3.1.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  flutter_slidable: ^1.3.0
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.0
  loading_indicator: ^3.1.0
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.3.2
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.1
  toggle_switch: ^2.0.1
  chips_choice_null_safety: ^2.0.2
  flutter_speed_dial: ^6.0.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  bouncing_widget: ^2.0.0
  badges: ^2.0.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.3
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.1+1
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  string_similarity: ^2.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  sign_in_with_apple: ^4.1.0
  crypto: ^3.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't change anything in the code but built it 2 more times with different build numbers and now it passed the tests.

```
flutter clean
// then change build number in pubspec.yaml version: 1.0.1+1 to version: 1.0.1+2
flutter build appbundle --release
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using this package and its unable to fetch the admin

https://pub.dev/packages/device_policy_manager

Please remove this package if not used or if used please check the manifest if you have added

```dart
...
  <receiver android:name="device.policy.manager.DeviceAdmin" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/policies" />
      <intent-filter android:exported="true">
          <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
          <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
          <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

<activity
  .
  .
  .
</application>
```

Comment: I am not using this package. Should I use it to get rid of the error?

Comment: Can you add your dependencies list here please

Comment: Added them to the end of the question